# JavaFX setting Wingdings character to Label

Tags: javafx, fonts, scenebuilder

How can I set a Wingdings2 character to a Label in JavaFX Scene Builder?
I have set the font family in JavaFX, but when I paste the desired character from Windows charmap, it doesn't look the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it show up correctly in the preview?

Comment: No, it shows the rectangle as well.